# Free database for storing intraday tick data and querying bar (candle) data on budget hardware

Tags: database

I'm using a cloud machine with 512 RAM to store tick data in mysql, but I'm having trouble querying candle data. My current solution is to select all data within a time interval and do the tick -> candle conversion in the browser, but that calculation is too heavy for long time ranges.

I looked at similar questions, did some research on time series databases, even considered database as service solutions. (I'm still contacting one of them to see if they would provide the missing data for candles)

The question is this:

Given about 5 tick data per second (these belong to different assets),
And low budget hardware (512 RAM, 1 Core, 15 GB empty disk),
When I need to aggregate the data into candles of arbitrary periods,
Which existing database solution would be more appropriate?

My current solution is to store an additional indexed columns with time rounded to 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, 5 hours, 1 day and I wrote mysql queries which can produce `asset/open/high/low/close/start_time/end_time` rows according to these columns in an attempt to speed up the queries. However, whatever index I use and however I optimize the queries, they end up taking seconds (and not milliseconds) which is unacceptable.

Are there any databases built to solve my problem?

Edit: guys at tempodb said that they just added `first` and `last` aggregate functions to their api :-)
Min, max, first and last is all I needed to create bar data

Comment: Instead of aggregating later on, you could update multiple tables (4 for your time intervals (min, max, open, close) and replace the current value for the time period if its smaller/larger than the current one.

Comment: How many rows do you have? This seems slow even on that hardware, unless your core is oversubscribed, then anything is possible.

Comment: @Anna I noticed that caching the candle data increases query speed greatly, but at great cost of disk space

Comment: @BobJansen At the moment it's hundreds of thousands of rows, but of course it will grow. Then I will have to think of buying more machines and database sharding. If I can drop query time to milliseconds scale, it will support hundreds of queries at the same time.

Comment: I would recommend PostgreSQL 9.3 and the use of Materialised Views(MV). You could create MVs for each time-interval i.e., one-min view, 5-min view, 1-hour view and so on. The advantage with MVs is that it will only update rows when certain conditions are matched on the server side. See: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views

Comment: If you discretize into several tick lengths of interest, each tick length table will be a lot smaller than the original tick data. Furthermore, disk space is cheap. To update you only need to update the topmost row, which should be quite fast.

Comment: @Nurettin, I do not think you get around the delay using any sort of SQL technology. SQL was not built to handle tick based data nor time series in general particularly well. You should look at column-based databases, do a search on this site there are several sections that deal with this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently storing real-time intraday data in an application agnostic way](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/948/efficiently-storing-real-time-intraday-data-in-an-application-agnostic-way)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend de-normalising the data or using a document database such as NoSQL or MongoDB. These provide a speed advantage when performing select statements as there would be no need to lookup or join data from other tables. An advantage of using a document database is that they store data in an industry standard format such as JSON or XML so it should be easy to pull all the data client side and perform your transformations there instead of having to rely on your server to perform the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use HDF5/PyTables (very quick given that it's free) for the data storage component then use pandas to resample the data.

You'll likely be better off just using flat files than a relational database IMHO.